# Get output of findstr in variable

Tags: batch-file

Im absolutely new to batch scripting and wondering how can i get the output of findstr into a variable?

```
@echo off
set /p assetPath="Set asset path: "
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /r %assetPath% %%p in (*.png) do (
    findstr "guid" "%%p".meta
    if not !errorlevel!==0 (
        echo Could not find guid of file: %%p!
    )
)
pause
```

findstr will output
"guid: d46decd9d3bbf0d46b31a3d4ae0f18ff"
for each file which contains a guid, how can i do operations on this and save the guid into a variable?

Comment: Hint: `if not !errorlevel!==0` could be written also as `if errorlevel 1` and your code would not need delayed expansion at all, see Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576). Good demo code as posted by Magoo requires delayed expansion. `if errorlevel 1` would be nevertheless also in Magoo's code a little bit faster, not noticeable faster, but it would be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
set /p assetPath="Set asset path: "
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
SET /A COUNT=0
for /r %assetPath% %%p in (*.png) do (
    FOR /F "TOKENS=1*" %%f in (' findstr "guid" "%%p".meta ') DO (
    if not !errorlevel!==0 (
        echo Could not find guid of file: %%p!
    ) ELSE (
      SET /A COUNT+=1
      SET "FILE[!COUNT!]=%%p"
      SET "GUID[!COUNT!]=%%g"
    ))
)
FOR /L %%x in (1,1,%COUNT%) DO echo !GUID[%%x]! is guid for !FILE[%%x]!
pause
```

This should set FILE[*] and GUID[*] for the files found and report the results.

Comment: it only outputs " is guid for " for every file, also i think you are missing a " in the end of line "SET "GUID..."

Comment: Yes - quite correct and fixed. The reporting line had a mixture of `%%x` and `%%a` - these must be consistent.

Comment: @Magoo `%assetPath%` should be enclosed in double quotes except the path string is already surrounded by double quotes to make this batch file also work with paths containing a space character. I suggest to use delayed expansion also for `assetPath`. I think `"%%p".meta` should be `"%%p.meta"` and `!` on the __echo__ line with the error message should be `^^!` to be output. Well, the error message is never output as __FOR__ gets nothing to parse from __STDOUT__ if the guid string could not be found in the meta file (or the meta file is not found at all).